# Get the number of records from 2 columns where the time is overlapping

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am new to MS ACCESS and am having trouble trying to get the number of records from overlapping time ranges. This is an example of my data.

[example of raw data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsItP.png)

[image]

I am trying to do is to get the column number_of_records. For example, if there are 4 records added at 5.11, the number_of_records should become 8 as 4 records are added at 5.10.

[example of raw data with no_of_records column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3VF1.png)

[image]

There is a mistake in my image above. I forgot to mention that for example, if the time hits 6:00, the number of records should not add on to the previous records and should start afresh.

Do any of you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the correlated count subquery:

```
SELECT t.time_column_1, t.time_column_2, 
     (SELECT Count(*) FROM myTable sub
      WHERE sub.time_column_1 <= t.time_column_1
      AND sub.time_column_2 = t.time_column_2) AS number_of_records
FROM mytable t
ORDER BY t.time_column_2, t.time_column_1
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. When I execute this piece of code, I am still receiving duplicates for the same row of data, how do I remove this?

Comment: It's okay, thank you for your help, I have solved the problem by using DISTINCT.

Comment: This solution does not use `JOIN`, `WHERE`, or `UNION` so does not add any rows. Only an inline aggregation is used. So the *duplicates* you refer to must exist in original data source.